# Get view which is inside spinner android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am using custom spinner and I have a question about how to get a button view that is inside spinner or get TextView inside spinner from another class instead of inside getview() method

Here is the code to clarify it.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items,null);
    Button delete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    final TextView notetype = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.notetype);
    notetype.setText(list.get(position));
    return v;
}
```

This is custom array adapter view, how can I get that button in other class?

And another question, what will `getSelectedItem()` return in my example? will it return a view that contain both button and textview or just return the text value?

Answer (score 0):

The `getSelectedItem()` always returns the object you put into adapter.

For getting the `Button`and `Texview` you can use the `View` that comes as a parameter of `onItemSelected`:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    Button delete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    TextView notetype = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.notetype);
}
```